# VS Code and Unity OSX Error

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm having problems getting my VSCode connected with my Unity project. I followed all the standard tutorials and had everything working with 0.5. I updated yesterday to 0.7 and now I'm getting the following error. Tried to fix the issue, but no luck. Now when I go back to 0.5 I get the exact same problem. Tried with a new Unity project, same exact error. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
Starting OmniSharp at '/Users/Daniel/Documents/Test/Test.sln'...
[ERROR:OmniSharp.Startup] The project system 'MSBuildProjectSystem' threw an exception.
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.SectionBlock..ctor (System.String type, System.String parenthesizedName, System.String value, IEnumerable`1 keyValuePairs) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.SectionBlock.Parse (System.IO.TextReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.SolutionFile.ParseGlobal (System.IO.TextReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.SolutionFile.Parse (System.IO.TextReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem.Initalize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OmniSharp.Startup.Configure (IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOmnisharpEnvironment env, ISharedTextWriter writer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Did you try a full reboot?  It started craping on me and a reboot cleared it up.  The updated Omnisharp in this release and I'm guessing something isn't cleanly restarting with the Omnisharp server bit.

Comment: Just tried and still no luck. Updated the post to remove the info log items to better highlight the actual error

Comment: This seems like a bug, ti would be best to file an issue on https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/List

Answer (score 0):

It seems like OmniSharp fails to process your sln-file. Any change you could post it here or send it to us directly so we can analyze?